# IE WebDriver Not Working Consistently On Azure DevOps

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-iedriver

Here is the query from one of my developers who is trying his best to setup:

---

I could install the IE webdriver to the build agent and make some setting adjustments. Unfortunately I can’t get it to work all the time, randomly at some points it works and on others it doesn’t (with 0 change on either config or sourcecode). For some reason sometimes the driver can’t make the proper connection with IE and it times out. I’ve made all the required configurations on the server: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration including the registry updated, but nothing solved the problem indefinitely. There are cases when I can run 4-5 times with success then on the next it fails for no reason – also reproducible on my local machine, so I do think there is a problem with the IEDriver.

This is the error we receive some times and if I increase the timeout it runs for longer, but dies with the same error.

### [error]Error Message:

### [error] Initialization method Selenium_Tests__DEV_.SiteTest.startBrowser threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:60439/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.

### [error]TestCleanup method Selenium_Tests__DEV_.SiteTest.closeBrowser threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

### [error]Stack Trace:

### [error] at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)

### [error]--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)

### [error] at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)

### [error] at Selenium_Tests__DEV_.SiteTest.startBrowser() in C:\agent_QA_work\1\s\Selenium Tests (DEV)\SiteTest.cs:line 35

### [error]TestCleanup Stack Trace

### [error] at Selenium_Tests__DEV_.SiteTest.closeBrowser() in C:\agent_QA_work\1\s\Selenium Tests (DEV)\SiteTest.cs:line 53

So this is the state currently, if anyone has any idea on how to continue feel free to advise.

---

Please help,
Alok

Comment: Please try using chromedriver and check if the same issue happens to chromedriver too, in order to make sure the issue only happens to IEDriver.  And also try disabling windows firewall, downgrading Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver.

Comment: Thanks Levi for your reply. I have seen it working fine with chromedriver. I will try other 3 options.